# Dynamic Output Of Total Usage and Total Return Of Equipment Using Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi good afternoon/morning im having an logical error of how to properly output the ***total quantity of usage*** per equipment and ***total return quantity*** of that equipment.

example of this table: (***each table has their total quantity***)

**Table of Equipment:**

---

[image]

```
SELECT e.equip_ID,e.equip_Name,u.unit_Name,e.equip_Quantity 
FROM equipment e
INNER JOIN unit u  ON u.unit_ID = e.unit_ID
```

**Table of Equipment Usage:**

---

[image]

```
SELECT eu.usage_ID,e.equip_Name,eu.usage_Quantity 
FROM equipment_usage eu
INNER JOIN equipment e ON e.equip_ID = eu.equip_ID
```

**Table of Equipment Return Usage:**

---

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM equipment_return
```

once the project use an equipment the equipment will be record in the "**equipment_usage**" table then if the project return a specific equipment the return equipment recorder into the "**equipment_return**"

Here's my query i'm confuse on how to output the data:
[Sample Data And Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e29559)

---

```
SELECT 
e.equip_ID, 
e.equip_Name,
u.unit_Name,
e.equip_Quantity total_Quantity,(
SELECT IF(
  ((e.equip_Quantity - eu.usage_Quantity)
   +er.return_Quantity)  IS NULL, e.equip_Quantity, (( e.equip_Quantity - eu.usage_Quantity)+er.return_Quantity))) available,
(eu.usage_Quantity - er.return_Quantity) usage_Quantity,
er.return_Quantity ,
eu.usage_ID 
FROM `equipment` e
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_ID = e.unit_ID
LEFT JOIN equipment_usage eu ON eu.equip_ID = e.equip_ID
LEFT JOIN equipment_return er ON er.usage_ID = eu.usage_ID
```

**Expected Output:**

All Equipment Will Be Fetch Then In The Column Include the Available Equipment, Usage Equipment, Return Equipment, my formula idea to display this table is:

```
total_equipment as total_quantity,
(total_equipment - total_usage of equipment) as available,
total_usage of equipment,
total_return of equipment
```

---

[image]

*All Form Of Query Is Accepted Just To Output This Expected Table* Thanks In Advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need to aggregate *before* doing the joins.  It looks like this:

```
SELECT e.equip_ID, e.equip_Name,u.unit_Name,
      COALESCE(eu.usage_quantity, 0) as usage_quantity,
      COALESCE(er.return_quantity, 0) as return_quantity
FROM equipment e INNER JOIN
     unit u
     ON u.unit_ID = e.unit_ID LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT eu.equip_id, SUM(eu.usage_Quantity) as usage_Quantity
      FROM equipment_usage eu
      GROUP BY eu.equip_ID
     ) eu
     ON eu.equip_ID = e.equip_ID LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT eu.equip_id, SUM(er.return_Quantity) as return_Quantity
      FROM equipment_return er JOIN
           equipment_usage eu
           ON er.usage_ID = eu.usage_ID
      GROUP BY eu.equip_id
     ) er
     ON er.equip_ID = e.equip_ID;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e29559/19) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include usage_id in the final query because there are multiple equipment_id in usage table. I get the sum first before I do the calculation for available equipment. See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d40bb9/2

```
SELECT equip_ID, 
equip_Name,
unit_Name,
total_Quantity, 
total_Quantity - coalesce(sum(total_usage),0) + coalesce(sum(total_return),0) as available,
sum(total_usage) as total_usage,
sum(total_return) as total_return
FROM (
SELECT 
e.equip_ID, 
e.equip_Name,
u.unit_Name,
e.equip_Quantity as total_quantity,
eu.usage_Quantity as total_usage,
sum(er.return_Quantity) as total_return,
eu.usage_ID
FROM `equipment` e
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_ID = e.unit_ID
LEFT JOIN equipment_usage eu ON eu.equip_ID = e.equip_ID
LEFT JOIN equipment_return er ON er.usage_ID = eu.usage_ID
group by e.equip_ID, 
e.equip_Name,
u.unit_Name,
e.equip_Quantity,
eu.usage_Quantity,
eu.usage_ID) t
group by equip_ID, 
equip_Name,
unit_Name,
total_Quantity

Result:
equip_ID    equip_Name  unit_Name   total_Quantity  available   total_usage total_return
13  Linemen Safety Belts    set      20 20  (null)  (null)
14  3tons Lever Block       pc       30 24  13  7
15  1.5 tons Lever Block    pc       10  1  10  1
16  3/4 tons Lever Block    pc       1   1   1  1
17  5 tons Chain Block      pc       1   0   1  (null)
18  3 tons Chain Block      pc       1   1  (null)  (null)
19  Linemen Tools (pliers, wrenches, hammers)   lot 1   1   (null)  (null)
20  Extendable Ladder 21 ft. Fiberglass pc  2   2   (null)  (null)
21  Aluminum Ladder 10 ft.  pc  2   2   (null)  (null)
```